# Interrupt `request` In a `forEach` Loop to Improve Efficiency

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm building a simple web crawler to automate a newsletter, which means I only need to scape a set amount of pages. In this example, it is not a big deal because the script will only crawl 3 extra pages. But for a different case, this would be hugely inefficient.

So my question is, would there be a way to stop executing `request()` in this `forEach` loop?

Or would I need to change my approach to crawl pages one-by-one, as [outlined in this guide.](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-javascript-and-node-js/)

#### Script

```js
'use strict';
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var BASEURL = 'https://jobsite.procore.com';

scrape(BASEURL, getMeta);

function scrape(url, callback) {
  var pages = [];
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      var $ = cheerio.load(body);

      $('.left-sidebar .article-title').each(function(index) {
        var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        pages[index] = BASEURL + link;
      });
      callback(pages, log);
    }
  });
}

function getMeta(pages, callback) {
  var meta = [];
  // using forEach's index does not work, it will loop through the array before the first request can execute
  var i = 0;
  // using a for loop does not work here
  pages.forEach(function(url) {
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }

      var $ = cheerio.load(body);

      var desc = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
      meta[i] = desc.trim();

      i++;

      // Limit
      if (i == 6) callback(meta);
      console.log(i);
    });
  });
}

function log(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
}
```

#### Output

```
$ node crawl.js 
1
2
3
4
5
6
[ 'Find out why fall protection (or lack thereof) lands on the Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA) list of top violations year after year.',
  'noneChances are you won’t be seeing any scented candles on the jobsite anytime soon, but what if it came in a different form? The allure of smell has conjured up some interesting scent technology in recent years. Take for example the Cyrano, a brushed-aluminum cylinder that fits in a cup holder. It’s Bluetooth-enabled and emits up to 12 scents or smelltracks that can be controlled using a smartphone app. Among the smelltracks: “Thai Beach Vacation.”',
  'The premise behind the hazard communication standard is that employees have a right to know the toxic substances and chemical hazards they could encounter while working. They also need to know the protective things they can do to prevent adverse effects of working with those substances. Here are the steps to comply with the standard.',
  'The Weitz Company has been using Procore on its projects for just under two years. Within that time frame, the national general contractor partnered with Procore to implement one of the largest technological advancements in its 163-year history.  Click here to learn more about their story and their journey with Procore.',
  'MGM Resorts International is now targeting Aug. 24 as the new opening date for the $960 million hotel and casino complex it has been building in downtown Springfield, Massachusetts.',
  'So, what trends are taking center stage this year? Below are six of the most prominent. Some of them are new, and some of them are continuations of current trends, but they are all having a substantial impact on construction and the structures people live and work in.' ]
7
8
9
```

Comment: Why not simply limit the number of pages to begin with? `pages.slice(0, 6).forEach(...`

Comment: Because I'm not as clever as you ;), this works perfectly. Thanks man. I tried using a `for` loop to get the same effect, but did not think of this.

Comment: ☺️ Glad it helped.

Comment: Did any answer helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using `slice` to limit your selection, you can also refactor the code to reuse some functionality.

*Sorry, I couldn't help myself after thinking about this for a second.*

We can begin with the refactor:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise-native');
const {load} = require('cheerio');

function scrape(uri, transform) {
  const options = {
    uri,
    transform: load
  };

  return rp(options).then(transform);
}

scrape(
  'https://jobsite.procore.com',
  ($) => $('.left-sidebar .article-title a').toArray().slice(0,6).map((linkEl) => linkEl.attribs.href)
).then((links) => Promise.all(
  links.map(
    (link) => scrape(
      `https://jobsite.procore.com/${link}`,
      ($) => $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content').trim()
    )
  )
)).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

While this does make the code a bit more DRY and concise, it points out one part that might need to be improved upon: the requesting of the links.

Currently it will fire off a request for all (or up to) 6 links found on the original page nearly at once. This may or may not be what you want depending on how many links this will be requesting at some other point that you alluded to.

Another potential concern is error management. As the refactor stands, if any one of the requests fail then all of the requests will be discarded.

Just a couple of points to consider if you like this approach. *Both can be resolved in a variety of ways.*

Comment: I get what you're saying, and this would be cool in a small application, but your template literal `\`https://jobsite.procore.com/${link}\`` doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, you had `{}` where there shouldn't have been. This is really interesting, I'm going to be thinking about this approach, thank you.

Comment: @Blanknewkid Oops. Yeah, hand-coding with that one. 

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of stopping a `forEach`. You can simulate a stop by checking a flag inside the `forEach`, but that will still loop through all the elements. By the way, using a loop for an io operation is not optimal.

As you have stated, the best way to process a set of increasing data to process is to do it one-by-one, but I'll add a twist: Threaded-one-by-one.

> NOTE: With thread I don't mean actual threads. Take it more of a
>   definition of "multiple lines of work". As IO operations don't lock
>   the main thread, while one or more requests are waiting for the data,
>   other "line of work" can run the JavaScript to process the data
>   received, as JavaScript is single threaded (Not talking about
>   WebWorkers).

Is as easy as having an array of pages, which receives pages to be crawled on the fly, and one function that reads one page of that array, process the result and then returns to the starting point (loading the next page of the array and processing the result).

Now you just call that function the amount of threads that you want to run, and done. Pseudo-code:

```
var pages = [];

function loadNextPage() {
    if (pages.length == 0) {
        console.log("Thread ended");
        return;
    }
    var page = shift(); // get the first element
    loadAndProcessPage(page, loadNextPage);
}

loadAndProcessPage(page, callback) {
    requestOrWhatever(page, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            // retry or whatever
        } else {
            processData(data);
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function processData(data) {
    // Process the data and push new links to the pages array
    pages.push(data.link1);
    pages.push(data.link2);
    pages.push(data.link3);
}

console.log("Start new thread");
loadNextPage();

console.log("And another one");
loadNextPage();

console.log("And another one");
loadNextPage();

console.log("And another thread");
loadNextPage();
```

This code will stop when no more pages are in the array, and if at some point happens to be less pages than the amount of threads, the threads will close. Needs some tweaks here and there, but you get the point.

Comment: @KevinB Well yeah. With thread I don't mean actual threads haha. Take it more of a definition of "multiple lines of work". As IO operations don't lock the main thread, while one or more requests are waiting for the data, other "line of work" can run the JavaScript to process the data received.

Comment: Can be done that way, but as you know is more complicated. Don't know the OP background but don't want to mess him. By the way, if he gets the point, he can convert this to WebWorkers or child processes or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. This does work and is very similar to the example guide I linked to. But I was specifically trying to avoid this approach just to see if I could use a `forEach` loop more effieciently. I personally like @Jason Crust's approach of just using `pages.slice(0, 6).forEach(...` and I'll be looking into WebWorkers, sounds intriguing.

Comment: @Blanknewkid Note that with the `slice(0, 6)` it will load pages in packs of 6 and only load the next pack when all the current pack is loaded. I mean, if one of the pages last more to load than the rest, will hang the entire operation until that page is loaded. Don't get me wrong. I don't know how important is this so I try to give the best answer and all tradeoffs I can think of. If that way is enough for this project, don't hesitate to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to stop executing after some amount of pages (it looks like six in you're example). As some other replies have stated you can't prevent executing the callback from a Array.prototype.forEach(), however on each execution you could prevent running  the request call.

```
function getMeta(pages, callback) {
    var meta = []
    var i = 0
    pages.forEach(url => {
        // MaxPages you were looking for
        if(i <= maxPages)
            request((err, res, body) => {
                // ... Request logic
            })
    })
```

You could also use a while loop to wrap to iterate over each page  and once i hits the value you want the loop will exit and no run on the additional pages

Comment: This does not stop the `forEach` loop.